# Getting file handle from memory

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, memory-management, shared-memory

I'm attempting to load a relatively big file into the memory with the ability of accessing it via a `HANDLE`, as same as retrieved by `CreateFile()` for example.

#### WorkFlow:

1. Loading the file
2. changing several properties while loaded in memory
3. using the modified file for other purposes with a valid `HANDLE`

**I can't save the file once again to the HDD.**

There is an example over MSDN where i can create a shared memory: [Creating Named Shared Memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) unfortunately I'm not quite sure how relevant this will be for my assignment, as the handle retrieved by the function is a `FileMapping` handle, and the buffer itself is a `LPCTSTR` pointer.

Comment: Do you want to read the file into memory, or access it with a file mapping.

Comment: From the sounds of it your only real option is to make a temporary copy of the file and open and modify that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I dont know if i want to access it with a file mapping, it's a possibility, not sure if the best one, or even feasible.

Comment: I still cannot understand what your problem is. Never mind.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I believe the OP wants to open a file, make "virtual" changes to it that aren't reflected on disk, and then pass the file handle to something else which will then read the "virtually modified" version.

Comment: I don't think you can make a virtual `HANDLE` unless you extend the system at kernel level. So, I think a copy is what you need.

Answer (score 5):

Well, for all practical purposes you can't prevent RAM from being swapped to HDD, so I'll give you a solution that's just as good.

Create a new file `HANDLE` with `CreateFile(... , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY | FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE)`. This tells the OS that the content doesn't need to leave the file cache (RAM) unless RAM is scarce. And we already established that when RAM runs out, anything can be swapped to disk.

Next, copy the content from your source file to your new temporary file, and modify as you like.